# What's the "dot" for when registering an Activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm kind of a noob at programming for the Android OS.  I noticed in the books I have been reading that the authors have placed a "dot" in front of the activity name when registering their activities in the manifest.  I've looked around the Android developer site and I can't figure out why we need the "dot".  Does the "dot" actually server a purpose? Do I need it?  I have included an example below.  Notice the "dot" before "NewActivity":

```
<activity android:name=".NewActivity"></activity>
```

Answer (score 44):

As you have noticed the point is not necessary but it basically means: the activity class lives in the same package of the app. So, if your app package is: `com.my.package` then:

- `.YourActivity` means that your class is inside `com.my.package`.
- `YourActivity` means that your class is inside `com.my.package` (same as above).
- `.activities.YourActivity` means that your class is inside `com.my.package.activitites`.
- You can even do something like: `com.my.package.activities.YourActivity` which is useful when you want to have different versions of your app and use Ant to change the references to the package automatically.

Comment: The documentation seems to say that you need the leading dot to get the package name pre-pended. It seems an accident that a bare "YourActivity" works at all. Why isn't it interpreted as a class name in the (much maligned) default package?

Comment: as documentation is not same implying what source code is doing so it can be termed as an accident.

Comment: and what if I actually want my activity to be in default package?

Answer (score 32):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm

> ***android:name***
>   The name of the class that implements the activity, a subclass of Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity"). ***However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period*** (for example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), ***it is appended to the package name specified in the `<manifest>`***.

So given `ApplicationManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest 
    ...
    package="com.stackoverflow.android.geotask"
    ...>
    <application ...>
        <activity android:name=".view.TaskListListView" ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

then since `android:name=".view.TaskListListView"` has a leading period, so it is interpreted as `android:name="com.stackoverflow.android.geotask.view.TaskListListView"`.

Comment: I think it's best to always include the fully qualified class name, this way, the confusing dot can be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

That dot will append your `package` in your application manifest.

If your package name is `com.app.demo`.

```
<activity android:name=".HelloWorldActivity">
```

It means that Activity is lying inside demo package.

You can replace this with

```
<activity android:name="com.app.demo.HelloWorldActivity">
```