# android weird error while launching application

Tags: android, android-manifest, launch

I am getting this error while launching the app, and I have checked the manifest file and the activities are there. Rathbones is the main activity.

```
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.rathbones.src/com.rathbones.src.RathbonesActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.rathbones.src.RathbonesActivity
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1739)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.rathbones.src.RathbonesActivity
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1301)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1730)
10-19 13:27:14.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     ... 11 more
10-19 13:27:14.806: WARN/ActivityManager(78):   Force finishing activity com.rathbones.src/.RathbonesActivity
```

Answer (score 2):

check if the `.RathbonesActivity` activity is in your main package say `com.activity.RathbonesActivity`

or to be sure write full path in activity declaration in manifest as `com.packagename.RathbonesActivity`

check this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834122/whats-the-dot-for-when-registering-an-activity) to understand what the "." dot means and how to use it.