# Leading dot in android:name really required?

Tags: android, manifest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the “dot” for when registering an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834122/whats-the-dot-for-when-registering-an-activity)

In all Android examples names of Activities, Services, etc. all start with a dot:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
```

I forgot to do this in all Android projects - but they do work perfect.

My question: Is this leading dot really required?

**EDIT:** Here's a small snapshot example from one of my apps. This app works perfect. It doesn't use qualified names and it doesn't use dots:

```
<activity
        android:exported="false"
    android:name="Tankvorgaenge" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>

<activity android:name="Tankvorgangdetails" />
<activity android:name="Tankvorgangdetailsbearbeiten" />
<activity android:name="TankvorgangUebersicht" />
<activity android:name="Verbrauch" />

<service android:name="MyService" />
```

Comment: I noticed that using the older ADT/SDK it doesn't have a dot, but the newer do it automatically... from what I've seen.

Comment: From painful experience, I always use dot, not the full classname.  This is after I had crashes in an app on some phones with certain API levels and not just API related, 2 HTC Desires, both 2.3.  One crashed, one didn't!  I've never found a reason for it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Omitting the dot and not fully qualifying the package/class name will work if and only if the specified class is not part of a subpackage within your application.

If your application package name is `com.example.myapp`, and you have an activity class `com.example.myapp.MyActivity`:

1. `android:name="MyActivity"` will work.
2. `android:name=".MyActivity"` will work.
3. `android:name="com.example.myapp.MyActivity"` will work.

But if you have the same application package and an activity class in a subpackage within your source tree such as `com.example.myapp.myactivities.MyActivity` things change.

1. `android:name=".myactivities.MyActivity"` will work
2. `android:name="com.example.myapp.myactivities.MyActivity"` will work
3. `android:name="MyActivity"` **will not work**
4. `android:name="myactivities.MyActivity"` **will not work**

3 doesn't work because that will infer that the class name you mean is actually `com.example.myapp.MyActivity` like in the first example above. A class with this name won't be found and you'll get an error.

4 doesn't work because it looks like a fully qualified class name, that is the system will interpret it to mean that `myactivities.MyActivity` is the fully qualified name itself, not the real name of `com.example.myapp.myactivities.MyActivity`.

You need the leading dot here to clarify that you're using a relative path, not an absolute path. If you specify just a class name with no package info at all, the system infers that the class is at the root of your application package hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

The dot is to use the relative path to the app gives `package_name`. You can replace `.MyActivity` with `com.yourActivityPackage.MyActivity`

Comment: Why do all my apps work? In none of my apps I use fully qualified names and I don't use the dot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `activity[android:name]` should either specify a fully qualified `package.Class`, or if it begins with a dot, then it is appended to the `application`'s package.

See the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#android%3aname)

Comment: Why do all my apps work? In none of my apps I use fully qualified names and I don't use the dot.

Answer (score 0):

It is required. It is an abbreviation for the package name. android:name is supposed to specify the full class name. By putting in a leading dot, we can indicate that the following class name is within the "package" declared above in the manifest.

Comment: Why do all my apps work? In none of my apps I use fully qualified names and I don't use the dot.