# Fcm integration getting the exception

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on the `FCM` integration but getting the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "service.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rk.servicepractise-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]`

I have searched it about but did not get the proper solution yet,Please check my code below and let me know where am i doing wrong?

Please check my `classes`  and `manifest` file with `gradle`, Please  help me to short out from this problem.
My first class that is the `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` which extends **FirebaseInstanceIdService** class

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //Getting registration token
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        //Displaying token on logcat
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
        //Not required for current project
    }
}
```

And one more class for the `Fcm` that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` class which are as follow:-

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    //It is same as we did in earlier posts
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And here below is my Manifest file entry for this `Fcm`

```
<application>
.
.
.
.

  <service
        android:name="com.rk.servicepractise.service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.rk.servicepractise.service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    </application>
```

And the `gradle` which i am using for it as follow **Module:app**:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
.
.
.
.
.

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle** foe the `Project:ProjectName`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

And the below is the **Exception** which i am getting:-

```
                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rk.servicepractise-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2779)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1404)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rk.servicepractise-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2776)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1404) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 
                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

**EDITED** Please follow this link whenever u become stuck in the same problem thanks **@Marcin Orlowski** ...*Link*:-[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12133152/1235698)

Comment: please replce your firebase complie line with this 
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'

Comment: @RujulGandhi ...Same problem is occring while i have changed the complie gradle which have u suggested

Comment: Are you sure your both classes (MyFirebaseMessagingService , MyFirebaseInstanceIDService) are inside your "service" folder ? please check it and make sure your code doesn’t contain any permission related GCM. if any permission regarding GCM then remove that and then check it. @Ravindra Kushwaha.

Comment: yes @RujulGandhi ..My both classes inside the service package..I have not any permission like gcm please check my 'manifest' and 'gradle' files.

Comment: please update your whole mainfest with all permissions ?@Ravindra Kushwaha

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just add dot (**.**) before `Service` in your `Mainfest` file.

In other words, the following does the trick:

```
<service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
```

Comment: ..Thanks for your reply...But i did not get, what are you trying to explain

Comment: @raj-gohel please be more descriptive next time. SO is often used by other people than OP to look for their problems' solutions so having cryptic answer (even it helps OP) is barely useful

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Sir, what i have to do now ?? remove the  service inside the "service.MyFirebaseMessagingService" ?? Please help

Comment: <service android:name=".Sercie.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
               </intent-filter>
           </service>


           <service android:name=".Service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
               </intent-filter>
           </service>

Comment: No, read the **answer** I linked to. And then, once you understand why, just add dot (`.`) in your `android:name` tags, so it looks like `<service            android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">`. Note that in your question you use `service`, not `Service`. Case matters

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Sir.. Thanks i got.. :)

Comment: @RajGohel Thanks ..It work  ..Accepting urs answer :)

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to replace

`<service android:name="MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">`

with

`<service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">`

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well!

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth, I've solved this issue by moving my FirebaseMessagingService listener class into the root package folder. I was using android:name=".fcm.FCMListenerService", and it kept crashing as described above whenever the device received a noti. Moving it to the root package folder it started working i.e. android:name=".FCMListenerService".

UPDATE: I moved my service back to the fcm folder and it continued to work, so this isn't the answer. However, it did do something to kick the thing into life, so it might be worth a go (I was fighting this issue for a few hours).

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error, and fixed it by doing a Clean and then Rebuild. I think the file was not getting referenced properly until the project was re-indexed.