# Get FCM notification, APP exit immediately

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can get the content of the notification, but I will exit the APP
immediately after receiving the message

I have tried to change the permissions, but it is still unable to solve this problem
This is how I get notifications

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('message');
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) {
      print(value);
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
      print(event.notification.title);
      widget.title = event.notification.title;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Firebase message'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(widget.title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my error

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(28007): broadcast received for message
W/om.example.try(28007): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/om.example.try(28007): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/om.example.try(28007): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/om.example.try(28007): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/AndroidRuntime(28007): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(28007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28007): Process: com.example.try2, PID: 28007
E/AndroidRuntime(28007): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.try2.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.try2.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~miA_E951nYH_yhkMq_5LQw==/com.example.try2-KPYqGUQO218syRAWeGkXrw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~miA_E951nYH_yhkMq_5LQw==/com.example.try2-KPYqGUQO218syRAWeGkXrw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~miA_E951nYH_yhkMq_5LQw==/com.example.try2-KPYqGUQO218syRAWeGkXrw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64, /product/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4198)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.try2.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~miA_E951nYH_yhkMq_5LQw==/com.example.try2-KPYqGUQO218syRAWeGkXrw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~miA_E951nYH_yhkMq_5LQw==/com.example.try2-KPYqGUQO218syRAWeGkXrw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~miA_E951nYH_yhkMq_5LQw==/com.example.try2-KPYqGUQO218syRAWeGkXrw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64, /product/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:129)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:66)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4177)
E/AndroidRuntime(28007):        ... 8 more
I/Process (28007): Sending signal. PID: 28007 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: Please post your android Manifest file.

Comment: Also, see if any of the suggestions here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561289/fcm-integration-getting-the-exception work for you.