# SecurityException: Permission Denial if starting Activity from PreferenceScreen xml and having productFlavors with applicationId

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a preferences screen with an option to start one of my activities by definition like this

```
<Preference android:title="@string/account_details">
        <intent android:targetPackage="com.company.appname"
            android:targetClass="com.company.appname.activities.AccountDetailsActivity"/>
    </Preference>
```

The problem is since I added a product flavor in my grade file and gave it a `applicationId` the Activity start results in a java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent ...

Is it possible to solve it without `android:exported="true"`?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove absolute packages, change:

```
com.company.appname.activities.AccountDetailsActivity
```

to

```
.activities.AccountDetailsActivity
```

Some info: [What's the "dot" for when registering an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834122/whats-the-dot-for-when-registering-an-activity)

Comment: This works only for the Manifest. Here it leads to a ActivityNotFoundException.