# BroadcastReceiver not called when registering from manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, receiver

This is how my Manifest looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lcukerd.earphonereminder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="ConnectivityActionReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Receiver works fine when registering from activity but I want to register from manifest so that it can run even when the app is closed. What is the issue? Why is it not working?

Comment: How do you call it?

Comment: @JakubGabčo I turn on and off wifi. Expecting it to run when wifi reconnects. If thats what you are asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Android Oreo, receivers must be registered in runtime using

`context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);`

to receive implicit intents

You can still receive explicit intents and some special implicit actions, as boot_completed or locale_changed for example

More information look below link

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `.ConnectivityActionReceiver` instead of `ConnectivityActionReceiver`. when you Call `ConnectivityActionReceiver` The **Receiver** won't be Registered Since No Class is Found

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".ConnectivityActionReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Refer This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4834140/8117793) to know More

Comment: Is this Class is Placed inside any other Package (or Sub Packages)

Comment: you are checking in which mobile?  version ?

Comment: No, it is main package. "com.lcukerd.myapp"

Comment: @jyubinpatel oreo

Comment: you know about broadcaast receiver limitation in oreo?

Comment: @Luckerd Try a Highpriority Flag in Intent Filter as  I Had Edited the Answer

Comment: @jyubinpatel No, I don't think so.

Comment: @Luckerd If Your are Using Oreo Check For the Updates in Oreo. There are MAny Restrections and Limitation in Android 8.0 and Above for AlramManager a, BroadcastRecievers etyc

Comment: @Lcukerd please look my answers which helps you register through coding.