# Andengine new Activity - Manifest

Tags: java, android, android-activity, manifest, andengine

I want to start my Level1.class Activity with this code:

```
public class OverviewChapter1 extends Scene

SceneManager.mainScene.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        SceneManager.mainScene.startActivity(new Intent(SceneManager.mainScene, Level1.class));
        SceneManager.mainScene.finish();
    }
});
```

However, I get this error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 
{de.davidtheobald.thorsrevengeapp/de.davidtheobald.thorsrevengeapp.chapter1.Level1}; 
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1511)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1387)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3195)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3302)
    at de.davidtheobald.thorsrevengeapp.chapter1.OverviewChapter1$1$1.run(OverviewChapter1.java:89)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How I define the activity in my manifest file?

Answer (score 2):

Add **Activity** for `Level1.class` in your `AndriodManifest.xml` file...

```
<activity android:name="YourPackage.Level1"> </activity>
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608017/activity-name-in-androidmanifest-xml/8569511#8569511) for additional details on specifying the name attribute.

Comment: @aniug This looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608017/activity-name-in-androidmanifest-xml